# What are current fed converters? (SMPS)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I recently came across a term “current fed converters”, but was unable to find any good reference online.

What are they and how are they different from voltage fed converters? And when are they more useful that their counterpart? And can you use a normal voltage fed IC for a current fed converter?

Comment: Did you read: https://www.electronicspecifier.com/blog/voltage-fed-or-current-fed-power-topologies-a-critical-choice-for-users-of-multi-kw-power-sources  and: https://ece.northeastern.edu/groups/power/lehman/Publications/Pub2007/2007_3_Song.pdf which has references to other publications.

Comment: Great, that helps a lot.